Webkit GTK compilation fails due to libfreetype error
I'm trying to compile webkit-gtk 2.30.4. When executing the cmake command:
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPORT=GTK -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-10 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-10
I get the following error:
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY) (found suitable version
  "2.13.2", minimum required is "2.4.2")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindFreetype.cmake:162 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  Source/cmake/WebKitFindPackage.cmake:104 (_find_package)
  Source/cmake/OptionsGTK.cmake:38 (find_package)
  Source/cmake/WebKitCommon.cmake:58 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:173 (include)

I have libfreetype-dev (installed by libcairo2, one of the project's dependencies) and libfreetype6. I tried to remove libfreetype-dev, but then I need to reinstall libcairo2. What may cause the problem? thanks!

What if you create empty CMake project with find_package(Freetype 2.4.2 REQUIRED)? Does it find Freetype, or also complains? You can get more details with cmake -DCMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=TRUE ..

Are you cross-compiling? If so, you need cross-compiled libraries as well.
